# TelegramBot error. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscritable

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import requests
import time
import json

class TelegramBot:
  def __init__(self):
    token = 'xxxxxxx'
    self.url_base = f'api.telegram.org/bot{token}/'
    #Iniciar o bot
  def Iniciar(self):
    update_id = None
    while True:
     atualizacao = self.obter_mensagens(update_id)
     mensagens = atualizacao['result']
     if mensagens:
       for mensagem in mensagens:
        update_id = mensagem['update_id']
        chat_id = mensagem['message']['from']['id']
        resposta = self.criar_resposta()
        self.responder(resposta,chat_id)
    #Obter mensagens
  def obter_mensagens(self,update_id):
    link_requisicao = f'{self.url_base}getUpdates?timeout=100'
    if update_id:
      link_requisicao = f'{link_requisicao}&offset={update_id + 1}'
      resultado = requests.get(link_requisicao)
      return json.loads(resultado.content)
    #Criar uma resposta
  def criar_respostas(self):
    return 'Olá! Eu sou o EletroBot! Fui criado com a intenção de ajudar os estudantes de eletroeletrônica à passarem pelo curso! Em que posso ajudar?'
    #Responder
  def responder(self,resposta,chat_id):
    #Enviar
    link_de_envio = f'{self.url_base}sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={resposta}'
    requests.get(link_de_envio)

bot = TelegramBot()
bot.Iniciar()
```

I'm trying to build a telegram bot, but it don't keep running and I can't solve this error. Sometimes it just starts and crashes with following error:

[image: error image]

How I can solve this?

Comment: Please always post all codes and errors as text, avoid using images for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design doesn't account for the case where `self.obter_mensagens(update_id)` returns `None`. You start out with an `update_id` of `None` so it seems like the first time you run `self.obter_mensagens`, it's likely that it'd return `None`. You should check that `atualizacao` is not `None` before you do any subscripting on it.

Here's how you could do it:

```
...
atualizacao = self.obter_mensagens(update_id)
if atualizacao is not None:
    mensagens = atualizacao['result']
else:
    return
if mensagens:
    ...
```